# Undefined property: User::$load in ci

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I want to load session in ci,
Here is my class and its constructor

```
class User extends CI_Controller {
 function __construct() {
    $data = array('name'=>'Hussain','password'=>'rahimi');
    $this->load->library('session');
 } // __construct()
}
```

It gives me the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: User::$load
>
> Filename: controllers/user.php
>
> Line Number: 5

Could someone help me? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the parent`s constructor thus you are overriding it, replace your code with:

```
class User extends CI_Controller {
 function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(); //HERE
    $data = array('name'=>'Hussain','password'=>'rahimi');
    $this->load->library('session');
 } 
}
```

Check the documentation: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html